# Strange flush left C-code formatting in Emacs 24.3 of SLES 12 SP5

Tags: indentation, c

I see some odd Emacs behavior in C-mode recently.
I suspect that the change happened either when switching from SLES 12 SP4 to SLES12 SP5 (both have Emacs 24.3), or when switching from SLES 11 SP4 (Emacs 22.3) to SLES 12 (SP3).

The effect is that indentation suddenly seems broken while writing C code, and surprisingly neither a redraw, nor a `revert-buffer` does fix the problem.

When Emacs is unable to indent the code correctly, the code compiles fine (so it does not have any syntax errors in it).
However killing the buffer and reopening the file fixes the problem.

When formatting is broken, all lines are moved "flush left" as can bee seen in this simple example:

[image: C code with correct formatting]

When I move the cursor to the first line of code and press TAB, then formatting changes like this:

[image: C-code after having pressed TAB on the first code line]

The only customization I had made is set `c-default-style` to `"bsd"` for `c-mode`.

I suspect the problem might have to do with inserting a line break between "static inline" and the function type, but I want to avoid very long lines.

### Questions:

What might be causing this effect?
How can I fix the problem more elegantly than reopening the file?

Comment: What is `TAB` bound to? Do `C-h c TAB` to find out. That's the first step.

Comment: TAB is bound to `c-indent-line-or-region` (and the indent shown in the screen shots in one TAB).